# Zero's of an ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I like to prove that any non-trivial solution of the linear differential equation$$y^{''}-q(x)y=0$$ (where $q(x)$ is positive monotonically increasing continuous function of $x$) has most one zero. It is clear that $y$ can not have repeated root as it is non trivial solution. Now what happens if $y$ has two distinct roots say $x_{0},y_{0}$ i.e $y(x_{0})=0=y(y_{0})$ which gives $y^{'}(c)=0$ for some $c\in(x_{0},y_{0}).$ Now i am stuck. I also like to find the nature of $y$ and $y'$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.  Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Hint. Assume WLOG that $c$ is the maximum point on $[x_0, y_0]$. Then $y''(c) = q(c)y(c) > 0$ and $y'(c) = 0$. But this implies that $c$ is a local minimum, a contradiction.

Comment: @SangchulLee      Its means if ODE is $y^{''}+q(x)y=0$, now can i say the same thing ????

Comment: @SangchulLee    can i say again $y$ has at most one zero again...as in this case we get local maxima??

Comment: As $y''+y=0$ has $\sin x$ as solution, no, you can not say the same thing.

Comment: @LutzL please tell me where is mistake....

Comment: Here is some intuition on this phenomenon.

Consider a particle of unit mass on $\Bbb{R}$ whose position $x(t)$ is subject to the force $F = F(t, x) = q(t)x$. That is, $x''(t) = F(t, x(t)) = q(t)x(t)$. This force $F$ is *repulsive*, in the sense that it tries to push the particle away from the origin. So there is no bouncing-back.

On the other hand, if you consider the equation $x''(t) = -q(t)x(t)$, then the particle experiences *attractive* force. Thus depending on how $q(t)$ behaves in time, either the particle eventually bounces back or it moves away while decelerating.

Comment: Sir i am from pure maths...if possible can you give me hint in pure maths...thanks...

Comment: are you saying that in latter case either infinite zeros or no zeros??

Comment: You mean soution zeroes, not ode zeroes

Comment: @Narasimham   Number of zero's of non-trivial solution...

Comment: Isn't the problem completely solved by the first comment?

Comment: YES...thats why i apply bounty....

Answer (score 2):

Hint: look at the proof of the [Sturm separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm_separation_theorem). For more general information, see the [Sturm-Picone comparison theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Picone_comparison_theorem).

Comment: ok i am reading the proof as pointed by you...

Comment: but its gives information about two l.i. solutions...

Comment: I would advise to combine the style of thinking of these theorems with @Sangchui Lee's hint.

Comment: ok thanks a lot...