# Nature of solution of ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $$y^{''}+q(x)y=0$$ on $[0,\infty)$ where $q(x)<0$ and continuous and strictly monotonically on $[0,\infty)$. By using Sturm comparison theorem we can conclude that any non-trivial solution $y$ of ODE has at most one zero. Can i say that $y$ is strictly monotone? Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zero's of an ODE.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721748/zeros-of-an-ode)

Comment: But solution is not given in that question....

Comment: It's hint for number of zeros of non trivial solution..